# How do I use a letter or word instead of a number for an if condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am totally new to JavaScript. I was wondering how to use a word instead of a number in an if condition. So here's the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Click the button.</p>

    <button onclick="nextFunction()">Run Next Function</button>

  <script>

    //Next Function
    function nextFunction() {

      var inputA = prompt("Hello, would you like to begin?", "Y/N"); 

      if (inputA == Y) {
        var inputB = prompt("Good!", "Y/N");
      }

      if (inputA == N) {
        alert("Okay, bye then..."); 
      }

    } //End of Next Function

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I have a prompt that pops up for the user to enter in an answer. In the text box it asks Y/N, and in ifs I have inputA == Y or N. It works perfect if I change Y to 1 and N to 0 but I want it to work with the letters, and I might use full words later on. How can I get the ifs to read the words? Thanks!

Comment: That's a very strange looking version of Java you're using, what version is it?

Comment: I've removed the Java tag because this is clearly not a Java question.  Here is where I'd normally insert a snide remark about ham and hamburgers.

Comment: @ScaryWombat—not so, javascript strings can use single or double quotes: `if (inputA == "Y" || inputA == 'y')`.

Comment: @RobG - Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to run the code snippet below:

```js
function nextFunction() {

  var inputA = prompt("Hello, would you like to begin?", "Y/N"); 

  if (inputA == 'Y' || inputA == 'y')
    var inputB = prompt("Good!", "Y/N");
  else if (inputA == 'N' || inputA == 'n')
    alert("Okay, bye then..."); 
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button.</p>

<button onclick="nextFunction()">Run Next Function</button>
```

I just cleaned the code a little bit.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! I thought I tried quotations before but I must have done it incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in quotes to make it a string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button.</p>
        <button onclick="nextFunction()">Run Next Function</button>
        <script>
            //Next Function
            function nextFunction() {
                var inputA = prompt("Hello, would you like to begin?", "Y/N");
                if (inputA == "Y") {
                    var inputB = prompt("Good!", "Y/N");
                }

                if (inputA == "N") {
                    alert("Okay, bye then..."); 
                }
            } //End of Next Function
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And to clarify what people are talking about, this is [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) is a completely different language.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I am completely new to this. I know it's dumb but I thought JavaScript and Java were the same :/

Comment: Everyone starts at the beginning! Now you can make fun of others for not knowing the difference, and the cycle will continue.

Comment: If you cast to uppercase with `inputA.toUpperCase()` you can cover that user input condition as well in one line

Comment: Might as well do inputA.toUpperCase().trim() to remove whitespace as well if we're going that route.